# require not working with npm start command

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, require

I'm taking my firsts steps with js and node today, so I've created the following script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function callBack(){}
fs.writeFile('./abc.txt', "My text", callBack);
```

Very simple script... So when I run it in my terminal with `node app.js` it works fine, but when I try to run it with `npm start` it produces the following error:

```
Line: 1
Error: Expected object
Code: 800A138F
```

Also, my package.json looks like it:

```
{
    "name": "first_app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "requires": true,

    "scripts": {
        "start": "app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security"
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Add `node` before `app.js` in your script as well: `"start": "node app.js"`

Comment: '-' oh, that's just it haha, thanks man it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

in package.json add node before app.js just like this `"start": "node app.js"`